# Friction between two rough surface

Tags: friction

When two bodies move relative to each other there occurs force of friction between them. I wanted to ask if there were two rough bodies with different value of coefficient of friction. How do we compute friction then, please give an example if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction is not a property of a *single* surface or material, but of a pair of them.

There's no such thing as "the friction of steel", but rather, e.g., "the friction of steel on ice (0.03) or steel on steel (0.8)". And that is still not accounting for surface properties, temperature, etc. That's why coefficient of friction tables (check [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction), from Wikipedia) always lists pairs of materials.